Can you give me an example for testcase in Cypress to test SimpleSelect react.js component?
I have a SimpleSelect component dropdown container with a few values. I don't understand how to use
cy.contains();
or
cy.find();
to click on the component to select a value from the dropdown list.
Appreciate your help.
